# Algorithm to fit polygon lines to drawn pixels in Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, vector, graphics

Let's say I create [a JS tool](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/) that allows freedom to draw whatever I want on a Canvas so I can make a freehand picture using the mouse, something simple like this:

[image]

Is there an algorithm that can be used to fit a series of poly-lines to these drawn pixels? You would obviously need to be able to choose how accurate you wanted it to be, for example the polyline could have 20 points or it could have 1000 points, making it quite accurate.

Also I'm not sure how it would work since the drawn "line" is more than 1px in width/thickness. Like if you had a big circle that was 100px diameter, how would an algorithm be able to fit a "line" to this.

Is there a particular name for this type of algorithm, for fitting points to a shape?

Comment: Instead of trying to recompose a polyline from pixels, it would be easier to save each mousemove position as the user is drawing the line.  Then those saved positions become your poly-line.

Comment: That makes sense. What is the algorithm I would use to minimize the number of points though? Like in the above drawing, there are probably I dunno, 10,000 mouse points that were used? What if I wanted to draw a polyline using only 100 points in a similar shape? Thats what I'm looking for essentially. I think its called point reduction or something like that.

Comment: You're looking for path simplification algorithms. The most common algorithm I've seen used it the Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm which eliminates "extra" points that stray too far from an ideal line. Mike Bostock (creator of the AMAZING d3 library) has done a nice example showing the effects of eliminating "extra" points on a path: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/

Comment: D3 is amazing. I didn't know it had line simplification in there. Thank you. Feel free to create an actual answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to recompose a polyline from pixels, it would be easier to save each mousemove position as the user is drawing the line. Then those saved positions become your poly-line.

You're looking for path simplification algorithms.

The most common algorithm I've seen used it the Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm which eliminates "extra" points that stray too far from an ideal line.

Mike Bostock (creator of the AMAZING d3 library) has done a nice example showing the effects of eliminating "extra" points on a path: bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify

If you're using nodeJS, Vladimir Agafonkin has a simplification algorithm that's also adapted for NodeJS: https://github.com/mourner/simplify-js

Good luck with your project!